# How can i tell what version of TLS a SSL certificate uses in Azure?

Tags: azure

Is there a way to tell what the version of TLS a certificate on an app service in Azure a certificate is using ?
Is the data encrypted during transit ?

Comment: A certificatte doesn't use TLS (or SSL). Instead it's the other way around and TLS uses the certificate to provide a basis for encryption of data over the wire.

Comment: so if i have  certificate , i can use the tls 1.2 option.  For tls 1.3 do i need to enable anything in my app to support it , as I cant see it as an option int the bindings ?

Comment: is there any tls configuration on Load Balancers or when it spins up a new instance are those tls settings taken from the original app service ?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything stopping you from using TLS1.3 but I'm not familiar with Azure to give you an answer to your question.

Comment: according to Microsoft v1.3 is not supported for SQL Server or App Services .  Under TLS/SSL Settings The max version of TLS is 1.2 , there is no option for 1.3 ? I can however configure it in my .net app in VS as it uses .net v4.8

Comment: I have load balancer on my app service , when a new instance is spun up , does it take the settings of the app service ?